# How do I solve this 'Launching Box2DBuild' error when creating a new libgdx project?

Tags: java, libgdx

'Launching Box2DBuild' has encountered a problem.

Launch configuration Box2DBuild references closed project my-gdx-game-core

[image]

[image]

I don't know why I keep getting this error whenever I try to create a new libgdx project.

I've included a screenshot of the settings I used to create the project. Do I need to install Box2D, or does that come pre-installed?

I'm using Eclipse as my IDE.

Comment: I found lots of issues using libgdx projects inside Eclipse, so I changed to Android Studio that runs easily Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. If you go in Run Configurations and change the Main Class to the DesktopLauncher, it should run fine.